# is there any function in ramda that adds properties to an obj?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I new to using ramda so I what to add a new property in an object using ramda, like the example:

```
{
  id: 123,
  name: Mike,
}
```

adding a property like "age" like below

```
{
  id: 123,
  name: Mike,
  age: 20,
}
```

Comment: Look at [R.assoc](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc)